# named pipe callback takes 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

got wcf dll with client and server classes wraping it.

when my server uses callback it takes over 10 seconds for my client to get it..

what is going on?

only got simplest NetNamedPipeBinding endpoint.

got lots of code so I'm not sure what to paste here.

what can cause such a long time.

EDIT:
only first callback takes 10 seconds..

after this it works fast.

any one knows why?

Comment: First callback after compile or each first callback every time without recompilation takes 10s?

Comment: @regfor first callback in runtime.

Comment: Please explain exactly how you are measuring the 10 seconds (i.e. from when to when), and explain what your client and service are doing during the period between.

Comment: @NahumLitvin: And the speed of subsequent calls?

Comment: subsequent calls take a few MS. Measure by printing DateTime.Now() on on server before call back. and printing it again once it is recieved.

Comment: If it first callback in runtime, CLR can compile your server side calls. Other calls should be faster. Please ensure that it's not because of CLRs precompiles your server side code

Comment: @Regfor that sounds logical. how can I check this?

Comment: You can see process csc.exe as a child process for your service, but it can be hard, as compilation could be quicker. Also you can try process your assemblies with ngen.exe, it will generate native image for them and you can check whether your 10s delay is due to pre-compliation. But I suggest you not avoid this pre-compilation and please use ngen only for check. Also maybe for your service will be good to enable auto-start to minimize time for "warm up"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing helped. I ended up to add a fake call decorater. that sends the first call when the system is booting.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. This helped in my case:

```
NetNamedPipeSecurity security = new NetNamedPipeSecurity() { Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None };
```

Pass this security object when creating the binding:

```
new NetNamedPipeBinding() { Security = security }
```

The original idea is from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ff9d542c-863d-460a-a03a-a9023c70829c/). The thread was about TCP binding, but the solution presented at the end appeared to be helpful for named pipes too in my case.

Even simpler is to do:

```
new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally I found a setting that greatly improves performance of the first WCF request. The time came down from > 10 seconds to ~2 seconds.

Set binding's TransferMode property to Streamed both on server and client:

```
var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
```

Then pass the binding into AddServiceEndpoint server-side and into Channelfactory constructor client-side.

Answer (score 0):

How are you hosting your service? The first call will need to create the service which can be slow to startup.

When debugging I use Studio's built in service host, and this often takes several seconds to sort itself out. Don't think I've ever seen it take 10 seconds mind.