# First call slow to .NET WebService ON Datalogic device WITH Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a mobile device (Datalogic Falcon x3).
I've created a program with compact framework 3.5 And Windows mobile 6 pro as Platform.

This program call a web service on my local computer. (.NET WebService, the program has a 'web Reference' to the web service)

And as you can see in the title, i have a first call slow problem.

When i first call my webservice, it took 4 seconds to do the request and retrieve the data. After that, it took 0 seconds every times.

The data are a simple object

I tried a lot of solutions, like, configure the proxy on web.config, or set 'Generate serialization assembly' to on on the app (This last option is disable on my project)

So, is someone already had this problem and succeed to resolve this ?

Comment: This is not unusual in SOAP web services, as there is a cost to create the proxy the first time.   One way to minimize this would be to construct the proxy as the app starts up on a background thread.

Comment: see my old question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868479/named-pipe-callback-takes-10-seconds

Tim got the right answer.

Comment: @Tim Sure, but this is actually my problem. When the user launch my app, i retrieve the names of the drivers and the driver can select his name in the combobox. 
But, if the 4 seconds latency are at the beginning, he will think that the app is not launched and will click again and again like a idiot, that's why i want to remove this 4 seconds. I can put a "waitForm" that said "Initialisation in progress" but this will be not fast.  And i'm afraid that if the driver do nothing during a long time (during he is driving) it will took again 4 seconds when he want to do another thing with my app.